# How to apply df.min() and df.max() distributively over many DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalization

I have a list of DataFrames, all with the same columns, and would like to normalise the values in all of them to [0, 1], while also maintaining the relative scaling of the values between the DataFrames.

For a single DataFrame, I could just do:

```
df = (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())
```

But, how could I get the min and max values for each column across all DataFrames, and then apply the same formula as above to each individual DataFrame, using the collective min and max values for each column?

Here is a sample list of 2 DataFrames on which each DataFrame is normalised individually:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dfs = []

for i in range(2):
    data = np.random.rand(3, 3)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["one", "two", "three"])
    dfs.append(df)
    print(df)

for i in range(2):
    dfs[i] = (dfs[i] - dfs[i].min()) / (dfs[i].max() - dfs[i].min())
    print(dfs[i])
```

Comment: Ah, you have multiple columns.  Do you want the normalization per column or per dataframe?

Comment: Per column across all DataFrames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will `concat` the dfs to one df , and using the multiindex for calculation

```
df=pd.concat(dfs,keys=range(len(dfs)))
df =df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))
```

If you want to see the 1st df

```
df.loc[0]
Out[20]: 
        one       two     three
0  1.000000  0.576142  0.000000
1  0.559371  0.000000  1.000000
2  0.000000  1.000000  0.594986
```

Comment: Very elegant, thank you. I wasn't even aware of `keys` with regards to DataFrames.

Comment: @KOB Yw~ :-) happy coding

Comment: I have only just noticed that this still normalises each DataFrame individually within the concatenated one. Changing the second line simply to `df = (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())` fixes this, and I can then split the concatenated df on the keys back into the list.